# Reuse an existing context manager as a pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, contextmanager

I have an existing context manager that is required by multiple tests. Instead of writing a `with` block inside each test, I thought it would be better to make a fixture out of this context manager, and decorate the test with `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_fixture")`.

I could reimplement the context manager as a fixture, but this seems like duplicating code. So I'd like to reference the original context manager in the new fixture.

This is what I have:

```
import my_context_manager

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(arg1, arg2):

    with my_context_manager(arg1, arg2) as c:
        yield c
```

Is this an appropriate way to convert an existing context manager into a fixture?

I should mention that I'm aware of `contextlib.ContextDecorator` for writing a context manager that can be used as a decorator. But my context manager requires arguments, and these are not recognized when they are in a statement like `@my_context_decorator(arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: I think this is the only option available currently. I have my implementation of the same posting it as an answer because posting code as a comment will mess it up. If you don't like it, please ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a simple context manager, used it as the fixture and called that fixture in test.

> Note: Advantage of using context manager this way is if the test fails
>   still **exit** will execute. However, if you directly call context
>   manager in test and if test failed post-yield statements will not
>   execute.

createcontextmanager.py

```
class ContextManager():
    def __init__(self):
        print('init method called')

    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter method called')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print('exit method called')
```

test_checkcontextmanagerwithfixture.py

```
import pytest
import createContextManager as ccm

@pytest.fixture(name ="c")
def check():
    with ccm.ContextManager() as cm:
        yield "hello"

@pytest.mark.stackoverflow
def test_checkficture(c):

    assert c =="hello", 'failed'
```

Order of Output using 'python -m pytest -m stackoverflow -v -s' you might have something else. I think this is we want from the context manager.

- init method called
- enter method called
- PASSED
- exit method called